# Why Showing Error in Stack ? i used flutter swipable

Tags: flutter

/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_swipable-0.1.1/lib/flutter_swipable.dart:121:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'overflow'.
overflow: Overflow.visible,
^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:3787:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Stack({
^^^^^

```
            Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 200,
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              TinderCard(color: Colors.red),

            ],
          ),
        )

class _TinderCardState extends State<TinderCard> {
```

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Swipable(
child: Container(
color: Colors.red,
),
);
}
}

Comment: if you are using `flutter_swipable` it is old, you can fork and upgrade to current version and then use it

Comment: is there any alternative ?

Comment: maybe you can use other packages, Also you can create custom animation with `AnimationBuilder` widget